# Dynamic loading of jar and its contents

Tags: java

Can any one help me load a jar and its classes and methods dynamically? I need to pass arguments to the methods. I am doing a project that requires an integration with third party vendors. They will provide all their operations in a jar file. The jar file from the vendor updates once in a month. But I don't want to change my application whenever the jar is updated. I want my application to run without interruption and load all third party jars dynamically.

Ex: I am integrating my application with MIMS. MIMS is the one of the third party vendors. They will provide their operations in a jar. I need to call their methods from my application and get the results back from the vendor jar file. The method signatures, number of arguments and their order is always the same.

Comment: You really need to add A LOT more detail.

Comment: As someone who did that in the past, I think he meant by "dynamically" as during program execution.

Comment: Yes! exactly what i want is that... I want to load during program execution. Any examples?

Comment: Application runs on Glassfish server

Answer (score 1):

You can create a ClassLoader implementation that will load a Class from a file or JarFile (using JarInputStream, for example). 
See [this](http://www.java.happycodings.com/Other/code27.html) as an example.